# cakephp 2.2.3 - cannot get associated data with hasMany throught (Join Model)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I cannot get the associated Model data using hasMany through (Join Model) association.
I'm working with cakephp 2.2.3
The same find were ok in cakephp 1.3, so i don't know what's the matter...

Event hasMany ScoresToEvent.
Scores hasMany ScoresToEvent.
ScoresToEvent belongsTo Event and Score.

ScoresToEvent will have additional info, so i cannot use HATBM.

some code:

```
event.php    
class Event extends AppModel{
      public $name='Event';
      public $hasMany=array('ScoresToEvent');
      public $belongsTo=array('Entity');
      public $actsAs=array('containable');
} 

score.php
class Score extends AppModel{
      public $name='Score';
      public $hasMany=array('ScoresToEvent');
      public $belongsTo=array('Entity');
}

scores_to_event.php
class ScoresToEvent extends AppModel{
   public $name='ScoresToEvent';
   public $belongsTo=array('Event','Score');
}
```

When i retrieve data i get these results:

```
$this->Event->ScoresToEvent->find('all', array('recursive'=>2))
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ScoresToEvent' => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'event_id' => '7',
            'score_id' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'ScoresToEvent' => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'event_id' => '7',
            'score_id' => '3'
        )
    )
)
```

In this case i have to get Event and Score data.

If I try to use containable it returns that *Model "ScoresToEvent" is not associated with model "Score"* and this array, consequently it doesn't retrieve the Score data...

```
$this->Event->find('all', array(
      'contain'=>array(
         'Entity',
         'ScoresToEvent'=>array('Score'=>array('Entity'))
      ),
      'conditions'=>array('Event.id'=>7));

array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Event' => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'entity_id' => '17',
            'start_date' => '2012-07-24',
            'status' => null,
            'end_date' => null
        ),
        'Entity' => array(
            'id' => '17',
            'title' => 'y',
            'content' => '',
            'subtitle' => '',
            'type' => 'Evento',
            'avatar' => null,
            'image' => null
        ),
        'ScoresToEvent' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '8',
                'event_id' => '7',
                'score_id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '9',
                'event_id' => '7',
                'score_id' => '3'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Where is my fault? what part of code is wrong?
I tried this on a brand new cakephp 2.2.3 installation

Thanks all

p.s. The same code works correctly in cakephp 1.3
p.p.s. do not consider 'Entity'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is a problem of name of the model. Try to rename the file `scores_to_event.php` to `ScoresToEvent.php`.
But in this case I think that the bestname ofr this model is: ScoreEvent.php, is more appropriate.
After try to insert more information to your model like this example:
into ScoreEvent.php

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className'    => 'Event',
            'foreignKey'   => 'event_id'
        ),
       'Score' => array(
            'className'    => 'Score',
            'foreignKey'   => 'score_id'
        )
);
```

Comment: Grazie infinite, sapevo che doveva essere un dettaglio importante che non avevo considerato!!!
Ho cambiato il nome del file come mi hai consigliato e tutto ha rispreso a funzionare. In effetti ero rimasto alle convenzioni della versione 1.3.
Ancora Grazie!   

Thanks a lot, i know it has to be an important, not considered, detail.
I changed the file name as you suggested and it worked. I still used the 1.3 version conventions.
Thanks again!